# CruiseControl.NET force build not working from CCTray

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I really hope someone who is a CC.NET expert can help with this, because this problem is painful!

I have a remote build machine with CruiseControl.NET and CCTray running (version 1.5.7256.1)

On the local machine I have CCtray connecting through HTTP not .NET remoting.
When I configure the projects, I add a server through HTTP and use the following URL:

http://localhost/ccnet

If I leave [Set to pre-1.5.0 server] UNCHECKED, then it fails to connect with this error:
**Failed to connect to server: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

If I set to [Set to pre-1.5.0. server] CHECKED, then it succeeds and I can kick builds off from CCtray on the local machine fine.

Now, if I go back to another machine which I want to connect remotely, I follow same steps. Again, only pre-1.5.0 setting works. WHY?! CruiseControl.NET and CCTray are at 1.5.7256.1?!?

The 2nd problem and main problem which I think may be related to the previous; if I then use the pre-1.5.0 setting the pojects show up but when I force a build I now get this error:

**An unexpected error has occurred while trying to force a build.
The method or operation is not implemented.**

What am I doing wrong, I'm really struggling with this. I previously was using 1.4 versions and this worked fine, so has something broken? I'm using IIS7 too so don't know if this could be something to do with it.

Comment: what happens when you use the actual hostname instead of "localhost"?  Does that seem to solve the problem on your local box?

Comment: No, I've tried. It doesn't seem to make a difference.  In fact after fiddling about, I am now getting the same error on the local machine. I'm thinking it could be a bug because I've re-installed both CC.Net and CCtray and still get the problem. I was thinking of getting hold of CCtray source code to see at what point I get the error "The method or operation is not implemented".  If not, I might have to go regress & go back to 1.4!! Shame. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here. CCTray 1.5.7256.1. I'm the only person on my team that can't force a build. Yeesh.

Comment: Same problem here too with 1.6.7981.1 version....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at the tray app's source code for the 1.5 release (as well as the current trunk.) When connected to a pre-1.5 server, regardless of whether you specified the connection as remoting or HTTP, you will receive the unimplemented exception message when attempting to force build a project.

Looks like your options at the moment are to wait for a new release or pull down the code and modify (and I have no idea how easy backwards compatibility was maintained between versions...)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Why would the latest release have the unimplemented exception thrown on this fundamental feature? I don't get it?  The reason I used http is that I don't have control over which port numbers can be opened for remoting.

Comment: Perhaps they ran out of time? It may also be that most shops upgrade ccnet and the tray app at the same time, so they didn't expect too many people would see this issue?  For me this is a pain since we are planning to build a new server and run in parallel with the old one. When I find time I may see what it would take to implement that feature...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have configuration options that are part of a breaking change perhaps? can you post more of your configuration so we can check it?

Also after you save changes have you looked at the server log? it often has information about what broke. Especially the part that happens right after you change a config file and save.

I'd be interested in seeing log file information. Also, why are you using http rather than remoting? Perhaps show us some of your settings in ccnet.exe.config? here's my remoting setup which I believe is the default:

```
<system.runtime.remoting>
 <application>
  <channels>
    <channel ref="tcp" port="21234">
      <serverProviders>
        <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
      </serverProviders>
    </channel>
  </channels>
 </application>
</system.runtime.remoting>
```

also you may want to check security issues and firewall settings on that server. (windows event log for security audit failures, etc...)